# Looping for SQL select columns

Tags: sql, loops, select, plsql

Suppose I have columns such as test_1, test_2 and so on till test_40 in a table "test" and I want to write a query to select from column test_x to test_y where x<=y how to do this by looping inside the select statement.??

Comment: you'd probably have to go the dynamic SQL route. Why not just choose what you want in your client program? This also sounds alot like a non-normalized structure. Create a separate table that you can choose this data from

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?  This is sounding like it'll have to be done with dynamic sql, and I'm not sure how (or if) the syntax would differ

Answer (score 1):

use `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` view in the oracle to build the `select` query.

```
Select column_name from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name = 'Test';
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm

**Update:**

Here is the code that will build the `Select` statement dynamicly. please change the table `'Test'`

```
select  'Select ' || ename_list || ' From ' || table_name || ';' from 

(
Select  
       LISTAGG (
          column_name, ', '
       ) WITHIN GROUP (
          ORDER BY table_name
       ) AS ename_list  , table_name
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name = 'Test'
Group by table_name
)  T;
```